# Searching data from other form doesn't work?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I using C# + SQL Server 2012, Winforms. I have a main form and docking a panel for showing child:

Code to open a child [usercontrol].

```
pncontent.Controls.Clear();

classinfo.ucon = new ProjectUserControls.U_user();
classinfo.ucon.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;   // ucon is the declare of usercontrol

pncontent.Controls.Add(classinfo.ucon);  // now the child shown already in main form panel.
```

The search method in @U_user [is the usercontrol]

```
public void searchingdata()
{
    if (!txtsearch.Text.Equals(""))    // this txtsearch is declared at the top to receive the string from main from textbox named txtsearchmain.
    {
        while (dgvuser.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dgvuser.Rows.Clear();
        }

        string data = "select tb_user.id, tb_user.UID, tb_user.EID, tb_employee.Name, tb_employee.Surname, tb_user.UserName, tb_user.Password, tb_user.Status, FORMAT(tb_user.Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') as Date from tb_user, tb_employee where tb_user.Boolean = 'True' and tb_user.EID = tb_employee.EID and (tb_user.UID LIKE'%" + txtsearch.Text + "%' or tb_user.EID LIKE'%" + txtsearch.Text + "%' or tb_user.UserName LIKE'%" + txtsearch.Text + "%' or tb_user.Password LIKE'%" + txtsearch.Text + "%' or tb_user.Status LIKE'%" + txtsearch.Text + "%' ) order by tb_user.id desc";

        DataTable dt = ClassConnection.DBFactory(data, "tbname");

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int x = dgvuser.Rows.Add();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value = item["id"].ToString();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value = item["UID"].ToString();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value = item["EID"].ToString();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[3].Value = item["Name"].ToString() + " " + item["Surname"].ToString();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value = item["UserName"].ToString();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value = item["Password"].ToString();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[6].Value = item["Status"].ToString();
                    dgvuser.Rows[x].Cells[7].Value = item["Date"].ToString();
                }

                MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Found");//Test messagebox.
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not found.","Message . . . . .");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill with Searching string.", "Message . . . . . .");
            return;
        }
}
```

I tested it with a messagebox

```
  MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Found"); // you can see in the searching method.
```

The messagebox is shown but the datagridview does not refresh.

the TEXTBOX I fill string to search is belong to the main form and the button Search is also belong to the main form. The search method and datagridview is belong to the @U_user or child form.

Search button click in main form.

```
        if (!txtseaarchmain.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            if (menufrmname.Text == "user")
            {
                ProjectUserControls.U_user user = new ProjectUserControls.U_user();
                user.txtsearch.Text = txtseaarchmain.Text;//txtsearch is the textbox I declare in  the top of the @U_user child. And the txtsearchmain is the textbox receive the input in main form.
                user.searchingdata();
            }
        }
```

It means when I fill the string @Admin to txtsearchmain in main form and then I click the button, it send the string @Admin to txtsearch in child and then I call the Searching method in child as code mentioned. I need the datagridview to refresh the data where user status is @Admin.

Now, the code is reading as well in both sides main and child forms. The test messagebox I mentioned above tells me that how many rows it found as @Admin.

Means the code is working.

The problem is the datagridview doesn't refresh the data I need.

Comment: Where is the datagridview? You have many other issues in your code: For example, `while (dgvuser.Rows.Count > 0)` should not be a `while` loop but an `if` condition.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged